# Zend Framework 2.5 installation process + Nginx + Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, zend-framework

I'm trying to install Zend on my ubuntu 14.04 + Nginx.

1) I have downloaded zend via composer

```
composer require zendframework/zendframework 2.5.0
```

2) Tell php location of zendframework via include_path. Something like that

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/home/dmitriy/zend/vendor/zendframework"
```

Folder looks like:
[Zendframework folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY6pg.png)

At this step, I thought that everything is almost done, and i need to download skeleton application to launch index.php.

3) I downloaded zip form Zend Github Repository. Extracted it.
Created nginx entry point to /public/index.php.

What I get at finish:
Page w/o images,css, etc.

Console:[Console with wrong paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msWKX.png)
Links are not reachable...

Can someone tell me:

1) Is step No:2 required?

2) Why links are broken?

3) Zend(1.11) library have another structure, maybe it is problem here and I have download wrong files?

Or give me links for ubuntu+nginx guide, i could not find.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be trying to install ZF2 rather than ZF1, so you can drop all the old bad practices such as modifying the include path to include a library.

Please have a look at the official tutorials to get started: https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/

Short version: you can download a "skeleton" rather than the librar(y|ies). A skeleton is a fully configured Zend Framework MVC project, you can then tweak it to suit your needs.

On another note, most php projects do not use the include path to autoload libraries for a few years now, and use Composer and the PSR-0 and PSR-4 recommandations. As you only seem to get started, I'd recommand you read a bit on PSRs, and then follow a ZF3 or Zend Expressive tutorial to get started, and not bother learning a legacy framework (even though ZF2 and ZF3 are really similar).